# I can't use new StringEntity when I post Json with xUtils

Tags: android, json

I am using Android Studio with sdk 23 and jdk1.8.0_60 and I want to post JSON via xUtils's official way, as below:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.setBodyEntity(new StringEntity(JsonStr,"utf-8"));
HttpUtils http = new HttpUtils();
http.send(HttpRequest.HttpMethod.POST,
  .......
);
```

but for some reason I am not able to instantiate a new StringEntity object.
I am aware of Android Studio removing HttpClient in sdk 23,so what should I do?
Thanks for every idea.
(My mother tongue isn't English,please ignore my error of words and grammar)

Comment: try to use HttpUrlConnection

Comment: Use a simple library that will handle everything such as Okhttp.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:I download org.apache.http.legacy.jar(or copy it in your studio folder  ....\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar),then add it in libs,and I can new StringEntity by HttpUtils to post Json.

Comment: Android team is not going to update Apache Http library anymore nor will it be included in the future updates. You should either switch over to pure java implementation and use HttpUrlConnection or use a helper library such as Okhttp.